# Find common ratio of a geometric sequence given the sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ratio

I feel like I have tried everything with this problem. Here it is:
[image]

Since this is an infinite sequence, I believe the formula for the sum is found with the equation firstTerm/(1-ratio).

I get 6x^7 as the first term. However, when I plug this into the formula above, I do not seem to be getting the correct answer. I am new, so forgive me for formatting issues. Thanks.

Comment: You know that
$$
10=\frac{a_0}{1-r}.
$$
You have $a_0=6x^7$. What's $r$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time n is incremented it is multiplying by one more $x^7$. $(6x^7, 6x^{14}...)$

Using your equation $$10=\frac{6x^7}{1-x^7}$$

Comment: Thanks for your help. I marked your answer as best because your explaination of "multiplying by one more x^7" for finding the common ratio really clarified this problem for me. I found the answer easily with your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the summation to be from $0$ to $\infty$ to apply that formula:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 6x^{7n} = 6 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (x^7)^n = -6 + 6 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x^7)^n = -6 + \frac{6}{1-x^7} = 10,$$

so

$$1-x^7 = \frac{3}{8} \\ x = \sqrt[7]\frac{5}{8}.$$